# Help determining whether a function is a linear transformation $T:M_{2,2}\rightarrow R, T(A)=|A|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Again, here is the function:

$T:M_{2,2}\rightarrow R, T(A)=|A|$

I was able to prove that its not a linear transformation because $T(A+B) \neq T(A)+T(B)$ in fact, $T(A+B) = C$ where $C$ is a new matrix.

But I tried to prove $T(cu) = cT(u)$ and all I did was multiply a scalar by an arbitrary matrix and I got $c$ times each scalar and it seems to me that scalar multiplication is preserved.  But the solution manual says:

> T is not a linear transformation because it does not preserve addition nor scalar multiplication.  For example, $T(I_2) = 1$ but $T(2I_2) = 4 \neq 2T(I_2)$.

I don't understand that solution at all.  Proving the linear transformation aside, how is it that $T(I_2) = 1$?  And, $T(2I_2) = 4$?  Don't these just product matrices with elements change to the scalar multiple times the element and still produce a matrix?  How can these show the results as being just a scalar?

Finally, I'd love to understand the solution and how scalar multiplication fails.  Sorry if this seems obvious, I just don't understand.

Comment: Vertical bars mean determinant here. One has $T(2I_2)=\left|\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\ 0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right|=4$; is this bothering you?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen ahhhhh... I didn't realize that is what the vertical bars meant.

Comment: I think you are assuming that $\det(cA) = c \det(A)$ for a two by two matrix $A$.  In general, $\det(cA) = c^n A$, when $A$ is an n-by-n matrix.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical bars mean determinant here. One has $T(2I_2)=\left|\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\ 0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right|=4$.